# Can there be active THC be trapped in the evaporator?

Tags: combustion, adsorption

In relation to the vaporization of THC, when smoked, is it possible that there is any active THC residue that becomes trapped inside the evaporator after the flame goes out?

Wouldn't some of the vapor get stuck inside because the instrument is not a hollow tube?

Comment: I have whittled this down to a minimum and toned the language down a bit to be more professional.

Comment: It's a site on which we discuss science. "Blunt" is fine to use with your friends, but it is not very professional. If anything, this edit actually helps deter stereotypes of said culture, so you should be happy about that. There's no need to be insulting.

Comment: Everything you just said takes away from what science means.
Stereotypes? Who cares? Aren't we scientists? Professionalism? Are you so concerned with political correctness that you would stop using something's proper label? Since when did colloquial labels take away from the value and meaning of information in the realm of science?

Comment: I'm not going to discuss this with you any further.

Comment: The words of a man who knows he is in the wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When burning a blunt, joint, doobie or whatever, THC evaporates (bp of tetrahydrocannabinoles is around 155 °C). Depending on

- the length of the "object" , related to the temperature gradient between the front and the mouth piece, and
- the type of the "filling" and its adsorptive properties

a part of the vaporized material might condense and/or get absorbed in a colder region of the filling. Similar effects, such as the enrichment of nicotine in the stump of cigarettes have examined.

It is however unlikely that any of the transported and reabsorbed components can be inhaled from a cold "reactor". The relevant components are no longer in the vapour phase and the vapour pressure of the tetrahydrocannabinoles will be too small.